# Extract a specific value from a string in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql, select

Need help with a situation, I need to extract a specific value from a column containing string. The string varies over different records, but the value I need to extract is always preceded by the word "VERSION"

I tried to user REVERSE & SUBSTRING but not able to get exact results. Any help will be greatly appreciated

the table looks like this

[image: Table Sample]

Here's my attempt to solve the problem

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.USER_ID,USER_AGNT_STR,
  REVERSE(
        SUBSTRING(
            REVERSE(SUBSTRING(USER_AGNT_STR,20,PATINDEX('%VERSION%',USER_AGNT_STR))),
            4,
            PATINDEX('%.%',REVERSE(SUBSTRING(USER_AGNT_STR,5,PATINDEX('%VERSION%',USER_AGNT_STR)))))
    ) AS APP_VERSION
FROM TABLE A
WHERE USER_AGNT_STR LIKE '%VERSION%'
GROUP BY A.USER_ID,A.USER_AGNT_STR
```

And I want my results to look like

```
USER ID       APP_VERSION
1             2.3.1
2             2.3
5             2.1
6             2.1
7             2.3.1
9             2.3
10            2.3
```

Comment: And what results do you want?

Comment: A lot easier for people to assist you if you post the data in a way they can cut and paste it out for testing. In fact, if you can set the data up using a temp table then you will get way more assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it.

This assumes that `version` is always preceeded by a space, then followed by a space, then by the version number, then by a comma.

The following expression gives you the starting position of the version number (`9` is just the length of string `version` plus the surrounding spaces):

```
CHARINDEX(' version ', user_agnt_str) + 9
```

Then, you can compute the position of the next comma after that position, which signals the end of the version number:

```
CHARINDEX(',', user_agnt_str, CHARINDEX(' version ', user_agnt_str) + 9)
```

Both information can now be used with `SUBSTRING`:

```
SUBSTRING(
    user_agnt_str, 
    CHARINDEX(' version ', user_agnt_str) + 9,
    CHARINDEX(',', user_agnt_str, CHARINDEX(' version ', user_agnt_str) + 9) 
        - CHARINDEX(' version ', user_agnt_str) - 9
)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/markdown?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=239639f32f87e32a82ad1a61c25082dd)**:

```
WITH t AS (
  SELECT '{''HTTP_USER_AGENT'':''MOBILE/4.2.95, version 2.3.1, build 95 (iPhone 65;Apple ...)''}' user_agnt_str
)
SELECT 
    user_agnt_str,
    SUBSTRING(
        user_agnt_str, 
        CHARINDEX(' version ', user_agnt_str) + 9,
        CHARINDEX(',', user_agnt_str, CHARINDEX(' version ', user_agnt_str) + 9) 
            - CHARINDEX(' version ', user_agnt_str) - 9
    ) version
FROM t
GO
```

```
user_agnt_str                                                                    | version
:------------------------------------------------------------------------------- | :------
{'HTTP_USER_AGENT':'MOBILE/4.2.95 version 2.3.1 build 95 (iPhone 65;Apple ...)'} | 2.3.1
```

Comment: Hello @GMB: Thank you so much, this helped me a lot and saved tons of time

Comment: Welcome @GMohan! Glad to know that it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is always the word 'version' and then the actual version number ends in a comma:

```
  SELECT
    USER_ID,
    SUBSTRING(USER_AGNT_STR,PATINDEX('%VERSION%',USER_AGNT_STR)+7, (CHARINDEX(',',USER_AGNT_STR) - (PATINDEX('%VERSION%',USER_AGNT_STR)+7))) Version
  FROM
    [TABLE A]
    WHERE USER_AGNT_STR LIKE '%VERSION%'
```

This just looks for the word "Version", then stops when it encounters a comma.